# Read Apache ProxyPass from a conf file

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have several proxy pass statements for the same virtual host. I want to move those statements to a conf file that the virtual host reads. Is that possible? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I've put it in confs-available and enabled, added an Include line to the virtual host, etc. Nothing seems to work. It never finds the proxy pass statement and defaults to looking in htdocs.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Is `mod_proxy` enabled? If it's already enabled, try these steps:

1. Run `a2ensite <your_virtualhost.conf>`
2. Reload Apache configuration with `systemctl reload apache2`

Prefix all commands with `sudo` if your systems needs that.